# TypeError: newuser.create is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

I am having issues trying to add a user from a form to my mongodb. I am using node and express and have required those in my js file. When I submit the from I get a newUser.create is not a function. 
In my index.js file I have:

```
const newUser = require('./models/newUser')
// mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/UAW', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/UAW', {useNewUrlParser: true})
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

And in my route in index.js is

```
app.post('/user/signup', async (req, res) => {
    await newUser.create(req.body)
    res.redirect('/');
})
```

My newUser.js file is

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const newUserSchema = new Schema({
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    gmin: Number,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    type: String
});


const newUser = mongoose.model('newUser', newUserSchema);
module.expots = newUser;
```

First, I am not sure which mongoose.connect statement to use. One works but then I get the newUser.create is not a function and the other gives me an error before I can even start. So do I need the first mongoose.connect statement with the "useUnifiedTopology: true"? Or will I be ok with the second statement.

Next does the order of the next four lines (app.set and the 3 app.use) matter how I order them. Sometimes I get a throw error if I mess up the order. Does that order really matter?

Then the biggest issue is making the app.post route to work.

Also when adding anything to a mongo database do the name attributes from the html form have to match the variables in the schema file? So for example if I have "first_name" in the schema file but "fname" on the name attribute on the html form, will that cause an error?

Also in my mongodb I have an attribute called "type" to specify certain roles for the user. Will the variable "type" give me issues down the road? Should I just change it now to "roles"?

Sorry for all the questions and thanks for the help

Comment: You've misspelled `module.exports` as `module.expots` so the newUser model is not actually getting exported

Comment: Typo! @JasonRoman is correct.

Comment: Thank you Jason. I hate solutions that are as simple as a typo. Drives me crazy when its that simple. Any ideas on the other questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo Detected!

On your newUser.js

```js
module.expots = newUser;
```

you forgot a letter **r** there, it should be expo**r**ts instead of *expots*;

```js
module.exports = newUser;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code. Fix that module.exports